# Modify a web page appearance on the fly? Chrome and extensions

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

One website I use regularly applies a certain style on some DIVs that make it difficult for me to use. Every time I visit a page on this site I have to open the inspector in Chrome and modify this DIV (it is a big site, hundreds of thousands, if not millions, of visitors every day so I can not influence their design), something like this

```
<DIV class="article__body__style1 article__body--style2">
```

it is the "style2" that is the problem. Usually I just double click "style2" and then delete it, leaving me with something like this

```
<DIV class="article__body__style1 article__body--">
```

and now everything is fine. Since I use this site many times a day I would like to automate this process.

First I tried to use µBlock (adblocking extension för Chrome) but couldn't find an applicable option. Then I installed [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) that seemed to offer the functionality I was looking for but all my attempts to use it failed.

It doesn't matter if the solution just does what I do manually (rename the style to a non-existing style), removes the style from the CSS or something else.

Comment: Did you try stylish ? https://userstyles.org
Overriding the article__body--style2 css properties in order to get rid of its style

Comment: @FabienLeFrapper, While Stylish may work in this situation, it is not something I consider appropriate to recommend at this point. Stylish [collects user data](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=stylish+user+data), which is a policy I would consider necessary to inform people of, were I to recommend it.

Comment: To be specific: Are you wanting to change the class from `article__body--style2` to `article__body--` on all elements in the page which have that class?, or just remove the class `article__body--style2` from all elements which have it?

Comment: Thanks @Makyen for the info, wasn't aware, uninstalled. 

Comment: @FabienLeFrapper, To me the worst part is that they do not/did not clearly inform users that they are collecting data. In particular, it does not appear that they *prominently* informed already existing users when that policy changed. I don't actually know how noticeable they made the policy change as I was not/am not a user, but it is clear that a significant number of their users are not aware of the policy.

Comment: We can answer this question as a Chrome extension, but there are lots of alternatives for how to implement what you desire, which are probably more appropriate for this situation. There are many extensions which you can install that allow you to either load arbitrary CSS into specified sites and/or run arbitrary JavaScript on specified sites. In this case, with what you have provided (you have specified a class to change, not the CSS properties which are a problem), you require a JavaScript solution. The most common thing to use would be to write a user-script.(continued)

Comment: A user-script is some JavaScript written, or installed, by the user, intended to be applied to specified sites. There are multiple alternatives for the extension to install which will allow you to use user-scripts. The most commonly used one is [Tampermonkey](https://www.google.com/search?q=Tampermonkey). You will probably find doing this in a user-script to be, overall, a better experience than making a Chrome extension yourself. The process for doing so is less involved and you won't be nagged by Chrome about being in developer mode (loading unpacked extensions) every time you start Chrome.

Comment: @Makyen Whatever is simplest. The class is only used once on every page so all elements = 1 element.

Comment: Use [Stylus](http://add0n.com/stylus.html), a fork of Stylish without the telemetry.

Comment: i voted too broad as I dont see any code or effort arround chrome extensions. read the docs, show us what you tried.